# Download a file when a DLL injected to my process

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to use DLL to download an update for exe file.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include<tchar.h>
#include<urlmon.h>



#pragma comment (lib,"urlmon.lib")
int main()
{
    TCHAR path[MAX_PATH];
    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, path);
    wsprintf(path, TEXT("%s\\update.exe"), path);

    //printf("Path: %S\n", path);
    HRESULT res = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, _T("getupdate"), path, 0, NULL);
    if (res == s_OK )
    {

    }


}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  reason,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
       // MessageBoxA(NULL, "hello world", "wlekfjkej", MB_OK);
        main();
      /*  const auto thread = CreateThread(nullptr,
            0, reinterpret_cast<LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE>(main),
            hModule,
            0, nullptr);
            */
   }
}
```

So the problem is - HRESULT returning s_OK response which stands for - everything is ok and file downloaded.  But it doesnt...
How can i get this method to work ? maybe some alternatives to urldownload func to use here?

Comment: `DllMain` is not a place where you can execute code that requires other libraries. Those libraries are not loaded yet.

Comment: Using the same buffer for input and output of a `print`-style function is undefined behavior. Also, `URLDownloadToFile()` is notoriously buggy, and its error reporting is crap.  Use the WinInet API instead, for instance `HttpOpenRequest()`+`InternetReadFile()`.

Comment: @Dialecticus Well. What if i will create a thread for it. And do downloading in the thread? Do u know any solution for it?

Comment: Aside: what will downloading an executable from an injected dll buy you that you couldn't get with just downloading the executable from the injector?

Comment: @Kappa creating a thread in `DllMain()` is doable, but dangerous if you are not careful. See [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices) and [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)